# What is wrong with my jQuery code? Gives error that it's not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, text, input

Am using it in Wordpress, so I tried to change the `$` sign to `jQuery`, but that did not work too. This is the script:

```
<script>
    jQuery().ready(function($) {
       var name = $('#user-submitted-posts-wrapper').data('name');
       if ( name != '') $('.usp-title input').eq(0).value(name);
    });
    </script>
```

And I am getting the error:

```
 $(...).eq(...).value is not a function
```

What might be the problem? I am trying to prefill an input field with text that I get. The input field has a name attribute, no class or ID attribute. Is that better to use? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's `.val(name)` not `.value(name)`

Comment: Read the manual or Google the error.

Comment: 7 downvotes, for this? You would think that I have done something really really bad. Damn... Not everyone is as good in jQuery like you. Get a life dudes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$().value` is `undefined` (not a function).

The `value` property belongs to the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) DOM interface, [jQuery objects](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) don't have any property or method by that name.

jQuery objects provide the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set elements' `value` property:

```
$('.usp-title input').eq(0).val(name);
```

---

You may also get and set DOM element properties directly by retrieving a DOM element reference from the jQuery object through the [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method:

```
$('.usp-title input').get(0).value = name;
$('.usp-title input')[0].value = name; //shorthand form
```

Answer (score 6):

You've confused jQuery's `val()` method, with the DOM `value` property; with a jQuery object use `.val()`, with a DOM-node use `.value`; they're not interchangeable.

References:

- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `.val` method, not `.value`

```
$('.usp-title input').eq(0).val(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
       var name = $('#user-submitted-posts-wrapper').data('name');
       if (name != '') {
           $('.usp-title input').eq(0).val(name);
       }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `.value` instead of `.val`.

Comment: `jQuery().ready(...)` is perfectly fine...

Comment: It seems that you are correct. That isn't how I learned it or ever used it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Chad -- ok so please change your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `value` in Jquery. You can use `val` or `attr('value', 'yourvalue')`